# Pandas - shifting specific columns of certain rows based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a big data set on nfl statistics from 2005 - 2016. Problem is, there was a new category added in 2009, so my columns are offset prior to 2009. I want all rows that have 'NFL Season' column < to the 2009 season to shift right, but only columns 11 to second to last column (so [11:-1]).

I managed to do it this way, but it takes so long to iterate over all those rows (about 10,000). Is there a quicker way to do this? I tried to see if there was a way to use the `.isin` where I could say if the row isin my 'rows_to_shift', but couldn't figure out how that would work.

And like I said, there's got to be a better or more efficient way that I'm just not aware of while I'm still learning pandas.

Here's the code I've been using:

```
rows_to_shift = rb_df[rb_df['NFL Season'] < 2009].index.tolist()

for i in rows_to_shift:
    rb_df.iloc[[i],11:-1] = rb_df.iloc[[i],11:-1].shift(1,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
rows_to_shift = rb_df[rb_df['NFL Season'] < 2009].index

rb_df.iloc[rows_to_shift,11:-1] = rb_df.iloc[rows_to_shift,11:-1].shift(1,axis=1)
```

Comment: yup that's exactly it! I was completely over thinking the problem/solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I'm dumb for not thinking of this in the first place and wasting your time. Such a simple solution and I was over thinking the problem. There's no need to iterate, just call up those rows:

```
rb_df.iloc[rb_df[rb_df['NFL Season'] < 2009].index,11:-1] = rb_df.iloc[rb_df[rb_df['NFL Season'] < 2009].index,11:-1].shift(1,axis=1)
```

Comment: This is not a dumb question. It's a common question from people learning `pandas`, so it is good to have an answer on Stack Overflow. Basically, you should almost never iterate rows in `pandas`.